# Error during running of scala codes

Tags: scala

I'm trying to run some scala codes from the book "Scala in Action". Here are the codes:

**MongoClient.scala:**

```
package com.scalainaction.mongo

import com.mongodb._

class MongoClient(val host: String, val port: Int){
    require(host != null, "You have to provide a host name")
    private val underlying = new Mongo(host, port)
    def this() = this("127.0.0.1", 27017)

    def version = underlying.getVersion
    def dropDB(name: String) = underlying.dropDatabase(name)
    def createDB(name: String) = DB(underlying.getDB(name))
    def db(name: String) = DB(underlying.getDB(name))
}
```

**DB.scala:**

```
package com.scalainaction.mongo

import com.mongodb.{DB => MongoDB}
import scala.collection.convert.Wrappers._

class DB private(val underlying: MongoDB) {
    def collectionName = for(name <- new
    JSetWrapper(underlying.getCollectionNames)) yield name
}

object DB {
    def apply(underlying: MongoDB) = new DB(underlying)
}
```

**test.scala:**

```
package com.scalainaction.mongo

import com.scalainaction.mongo._

class test{
    def client = new MongoClient
    def db = client.createDB("mydb")

    for (name <- db.collectionName) println(name)
}
```

After compiling using

```
scalac -cp /.../mongo-java-driver-2.11.3.jar MongoClient.scala DB.scala test.scala
```

I got:

```
MongoClient.scala:7: warning: constructor Mongo in class Mongo is deprecated: see corresponding Javadoc for more information.
    private val underlying = new Mongo(host, port)
                                 ^
one warning found
```

It seems OK(?). But after invoking

```
scala -cp /.../mongo-java-driver-2.11.3.jar -deprecation  test.scala
```

it showed:

```
/.../test.scala:1: error: illegal start of definition
package com.scalainaction.mongo
^
one error found
```

How can I run **test.scala** without error? Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `scala ... test.scala`, you are running `test.scala` in script mode. That doesn't allow a package definition. You have two options: Either you format `test.scala` according to **script requirements**, or you write a **full class** (which seems you are intending) and run `scala ... test` just with the class name.

If you run `man scala`, you can see the explanation of the difference:

> The scala utility runs Scala code using a Java runtime environment.  The Scala code to run is  specified in one of three ways:
>
> 1. With no arguments specified, a Scala shell starts and reads commands interactively.
> 2. With  -howtorun:object  specified, the fully qualified name of a top-level Scala object may be
>                specified.  The object should previously have been compiled using scalac(1).
> 3. With -howtorun:script specified, a file containing Scala code may be specified.
>
> If -howtorun: is left as the default (guess), then the scala command will check whether a file of the
>          specified  name  exists.  If it does, then it will treat it as a script file; if it does not, then it
>          will treat it as the name of an object.

The last paragraph is significant.

---

First the second case, using a full class:

To run the compiled class, the following should work:

```
scala -cp /.../mongo-java-driver-2.11.3.jar:. test
```

This is shorthand for the following more verbose call:

```
java -cp /.../mongo-java-driver-2.11.3.jar:/path/to/scala/scala-library.jar:. test
```

But you still need to make an adjustment for that to work—you need a main class object. The following should do

```
object test extends App { ... }  // instead of class test { ... }
```

---

Alternatively, remove the `package` declaration and the `test` class definition, and just put the contents of the `test` body into `test.scala` which should run fine using the script engine.

---

A good starting point is the [Getting Started](http://scala-lang.org/documentation/getting-started.html) article from the main Scala site. If you read up on Odersky's "Programming in Scala" (the first edition is freely available on the internet), section 4.4 covers compiling a full application class, whereas script mode is explained in chapter 2 step 4.